# Add JInternalFrame to JDesktopPane in execution time

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I have a problem with a `JDesktopPane`, I add `JInternalFrame` on it and then show it on a `JFrame`.

The problem is when I try to add another `JInternalFrame`  in execution time.

I use the same method to add the same `JInternalFrame` but its dosnt shows up.

```
public class Desktop extends JDesktopPane {
    (...)
    public void addJInternalFrameBox(JInternalFrameBox jifb) {
     this.add(jifb, desktop.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
     this.repaint();
     this.validate();
    }
}
```

JInternalFrameBox class:

```
public class JInternalFrameBox extends JInternalFrame {
    (...)
    public JInternalFrameBox(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
        setUpFrame();
    }
    public void setUpFrame() {
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("test");
        lbl.setVisible(true);

        this.add(lbl);
        this.setPreferredSize(INTERNAL_FRAME_SIZE);
        this.setLocation(100, 100);
        this.setIconifiable(true);
        this.setClosable(true);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

jButtonBox the button that open the JInternalFrameBox:

```
public class jButtonBox extends JButton implements MouseListener {
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        JInternalFrameBox jifb = new JInternalFrameBox(id);
        jifb.setVisible(true);
        Desktop df = Desktop.getInstance();
        df.addJInternalFrameBox(jifb);
    }
    (...)
}
```

Comment: I don't see any way of guessing what your problem is based on the scant information that you've shown us so far. Perhaps you're not setting the internal frame to visible, perhaps you're not specifying its size or location, who knows? If you really need our help, consider giving enough information that we can work with. An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) works best for this.

Comment: "hello?..." <taps mic>.... "is this thing on?"

Comment: Nice code snippets, worth a glance.  I'll look at code closely when it is an SSCCE.

Comment: @JMira, so have you read the link I gave you yet??? Its about 5-6 lines of code to create, add and display an internal frame in a desktop pane.

Answer (score 4):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Internal Frames](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) for a working example.

Comment: +1 `JDesktopPane` knows how to accommodate more than one `JInternalFrame`; `Desktop extends JPanel` does not.

Comment: Maybe your problem is just that the size and location of the internal frame is the same and you can't see the second one. The tutorial shows the trick for displaying a new internal frame on top of the old one.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a JPanel for your desktop, but rather use a JDesktopPane. That's specifically what its for.

Comment: do you revalidate and repaint your desktop after adding the internal frame?

Answer (score 1):

you have to set both location and size of the internal frame, as in

```
    setSize(INTERNAL_FRAME_SIZE); // instead of setPref
    setLocation(100, 100);
```

hm ... maybe not (just saw the pack in your code) - no more guessing without an sscce, as others already stated